# How to fetch node value from xml string in C#?

Tags: c#, xml

For the following string xml value, I need to fetch the value of node "ReturnStr"

```
<ArrayOfAppExportReturnStruct
 xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ClientWebService\" xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">\r\n 
 <AppExportReturnStruct>\r\n    
 <Key1>0</Key1>\r\n    <Key2>0</Key2>\r\n  
 <PeriodDT>2019-02-26T00:00:00</PeriodDT>\r\n   
 <ReturnCode>1</ReturnCode>\r\n    
 <ReturnStr>Failure - No Deal found based on input parameters passed.</ReturnStr>\r\n  
 </AppExportReturnStruct>\r\n
</ArrayOfAppExportReturnStruct>
```

I used the following code

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlString.Replace("\r\n",""));
string alarmDesc;

string xpath = "ArrayOfAppExportReturnStruct/AppExportReturnStruct";
var nodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes(xpath);
foreach (XmlNode childrenNode in nodes)
{
    alarmDesc = childrenNode.SelectSingleNode("ReturnStr").InnerText;
}
```

I am getting nothing in nodes var.
What is the right way to get ReturnStr's node value in "alarmDesc".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The XML text most probably does not actually include `\r\n` or any other escape characters, that's just how Visual Studio chooses to represent the string when you're debugging. Parsing XML does not depend on whitespace either, so replacing these strings in the value is almost certainly not necessary. To select the node, you need to include the namespace. I suggest you use `XElement` rather than `XmlDocument`, because it's got a much friendlier interface:

```
var xml = XElement.Parse(xmlDocument);
XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ClientWebService";
var alarmDesc = (string) xml.Element(ns + "AppExportReturnStruct").Element(ns + "ReturnStr");
```

With more than element, use `.Elements` rather than `.Element`, in a `foreach` loop. You can even use LINQ for that if you're just interested in particular bits:

```
var alarmDescriptions = xml
    .Elements(ns + "AppExportReturnStruct")
    .Select(e => (string) e.Element(ns + "ReturnStr"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this if there is only one loop.

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlString.Replace("\r\n",""));
string alarmDesc = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("ReturnStr").Item(0).InnerText;
```